# Unity - Adding multiple array parameters in method (for adding multiple items)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, unity-game-engine, foreach, inventory

I'm trying to achieve a method that I can call to create multiple items

This is the method I'm trying to get it to work

```
public void AddMultipleItems(string[] itemKey, int[] amount)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < itemKey.Length; i++)
    {
        Item item;
        item = ItemCollection[itemKey[i]];

        for (int x = 0; x < amount.Length; x++)
        {
            if (inventory.CanAddItem(item, amount[x]) == true)
            {
                inventory.AddItem(item.GetCopy());
            }
            else if (inventory.CanAddItem(item, amount[x]) == false)
            {
                Debug.Log("Inventory Full");
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And then this method will be called to add in items like this:

```
itemDB.AddMultipleItems(new string[] { "Boots", "Gold Coin", "Apple" }, new int[] {1, 2, 3 });
```

**Result**: I get 3 Boots, 3 Gold coin and 3 Apple. when I should be getting 1 Boots, 2 Gold Coin & 3 Apples,

I've done a similar Method like this except it doesn't require array parameters and it works perfectly:

```
 public void AddItems(string itemKey, int amount)
{
    //First check if entered itemKey parameter exists in ItemCollection Dictionary
    if (ItemCollection.ContainsKey(itemKey))
    {
        Item item;
        item = ItemCollection[itemKey];
        if (item != null)
        {
            //check if we can add the item and the amount of it
            if (inventory.CanAddItem(item, amount))
            {
                //loop through the total amount
                for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
                {
                    //add the item
                    inventory.AddItem(item.GetCopy());
                }
                Debug.Log(itemKey + " Added Successfully!");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Not enough space in Inventory");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Null Item");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(itemKey + " does not exist in ItemDatabase's Dictionary");
    }
}
```

So basically another way of looking at it is how can I turn the **AddItems(string itemKey, int amount)** into **AddItems(string[] itemKey, int[] amount)**. its the for loop, foreach loop and arrays that are kinda tripping me over since I'm not very good at those.

Appreciate any help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every `item` you are iterating over the entire `amount` array which has 3 entries. I would actually expect that for each item you get `1+2+3 = 6` items added.

Wouldn't you rather want to only get the amount to add from the **one** entry in `amount` with the same index as the given itemKey: `amount[i]`

```c#
public void AddMultipleItems(string[] itemKey, int[] amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemKey.Length; i++)
    {
        Item item;
        item = ItemCollection[itemKey[i]];

        if (inventory.CanAddItem(item, amount[i]))
        {
            inventory.AddItem(item.GetCopy());
        }
        else // your if condition here was redundant
        {
            Debug.Log("Inventory Full");
        }
    }
}
```

---

In general you already have a method for adding a single item so I wouldn't re-implement that for multiple ones but rather call it from the loop like

```c#
public void AddMultipleItems(string[] itemKey, int[] amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemKey.Length; i++)
    {
        // Instead of re-implement rather call your existing method
        // and treat each value pair as if ti was a single add call
        AddItems(itemKey[i], amount[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Then passing in two separate arrays is pretty error prone and hard to maintain. I would probably rather pass in a `Dictionary<string, int>` like e.g.

```c#
public void AddMultipleItems(Dictionary<string, int> itemsToAdd)
{
    foreach (var kvp in itemsToAdd)
    {
        AddItems(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

and then call it like

```c#
 itemDB.AddMultipleItems(new Dictionary<string, int>{ {"Boots", 1}, {"Gold Coin", 2}, {"Apple", 3}});
```

Comment: You're right, its best to just reuse my Additems() method for 1 item. I did think about reusing it before but just didn't know how the for loop etc would work. Whenever I deal with loops, it feels like my brain is in a maze lol.  Anyways Thanks for your help the reusing method one worked.

Comment: `Whenever I deal with loops, it feels like my brain is in a maze lol` ^^ That's even more reason to split it up into individual methods whenever possible ;) It is always good practice to start with the minimal (atomic) solution (like here adding a single item) and then if this works increase complexity but re-using your atomic solution. This way you can e.g. also extend or alter the way one single items is added without having to touch the multiple method at all since all you have to asure is that the single add works